# Read-only Scope for Gmail Oauth IMAP

Tags: oauth, gmail

Is there a way to access gmail through oauth with read-only permission? I found this scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly but it doesn't work.

I receive a token using the readonly scope, but when I try to use it I get:

Net::IMAP::NoResponseError:  Invalid credentials (Failure)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Proper scopes are following:

```
scope: ['https://mail.google.com/', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly` scope does only provide access to GMail API.

But you try to use IMAP, which is not included in `gmail.readonly`. Only in the full `https://mail.google.com/` scope.